# Unity Container - Dependency Injection of Dynamic DbContext into Service

Tags: .net, asp.net-web-api, dependency-injection, unity-container

I'm building a .Net Web API which uses a Service+Repository pattern w/ Entity Framework.  Each controller's CRUD actions relay data retrieved by calls to a Service.

I have a SomeContext that extends DbContext:

```
public class SomeContext : DbContext
{
    public SomeContext(string connString) : base(connString) { }

    // DbSets
    ...
}
```

The Service is initialized w/ a constructor that accepts an ISomeContext:

```
public class Service : IService
{
    public Service(ISomeContext ctx) : base(ctx)
    {
        _alpha = new AlphaRepository(ctx);
        ...
    }

    GetAllAlpha()
    {
        return _alpha.Get();
    }
    ...
}
```

I want to use (Unity Container) Dependency Injection to inject an instance of SomeContext into the Service constructor.  The life cycle of a given SomeContext should be the duration of the API request.  The difficulty is that the connection string for SomeContext is dynamic and cannot be known until a runtime parameter 'client' is provided as part of the API request.

Furthermore, there are an indeterminate number of clients and therefore connection strings due to my database-per-tenant environment.  As such, I cannot just register *n* known SomeContexts and Resolve() based on the 'client' parameter.

Instead, an internally developed NuGet package w/ exposed ContextFactory lets me retrieve the appropriate SomeContext for a client:

```
ContextFactory.GetClientContext(client);
```

How and where do I configure Unity Container to manage this dynamic SomeContext?

Additional notes:

- Unity is already dependency injecting the IService Service into each
  of my Controller actions.  Because of this, the Service constructor is
  executed prior to any of the Web API ActionFilters I have created.  This means I can't identify the 'client' prior to the injection...I presume this means I would need to use a factory and/or delegate...?
- I've read about using an abstract factory in conjunction with a delegate    for the DbContext, `public delegate IDbContext CreateDbContext(string client);`, and adapter for the NuGet
  package's GetClientContext request, but I haven't been able to
  piece it all together into a working solution.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Seeing your previous question I still don't understand what you mean by "the DbContext is dynamic". I can't imagine that you actually have different context *classes* so you probably mean that the context is identical but merely that the connection string differs. Also, please be more specific about the life cycle of a context instance.

Comment: Oh yeah, sorry for the confusion. The D̶b̶C̶o̶n̶t̶e̶x̶t̶s̶ SomeContexts are the same; they have the same DbSets, etc. They differ only because, as you surmised, they are initialized with different connection strings. The life cycle of a given SomeContext should be per web request. I have updated my question to make these clarifications. Thanks for your attention to this :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick to incorporate runtime parameters into a Unity Dependency Injected object is [InjectionFactory](https://unitycontainer.github.io/api/Unity.Injection.InjectionFactory.html):

```
container.RegisterType<ISomeContext>(
    new PerRequestLifetimeManager(),
    new InjectionFactory(_ => ContextFactoryAdapter.GetSomeContext(new HttpContextWrapper(HttpContext.Current)))
);
```

> `InjectionFactory` lets you specify a factory method the container will use to create the object

In this case, I designate the static ContextFactoryAdapter.GetSomeContext() method to return a dynamic SomeContext according to data available in the supplied HttpContextWrapper argument:

```
public static SomeContext GetSomeContext(HttpContextWrapper requestWrapper)
{
    var client = requestWrapper.Request.QueryString["client"];

    return ContextFactory.GetClientContext(client);
}
```

So, Unity will resolve ISomeContext type to the SomeContext returned by GetClientContext().

The `PerRequestLifetimeManager()` argument to RegisterType() instructs Unity to use the returned SomeContext instance for the lifetime of a single HTTP request.  For Unity to dispose of the instance automatically, you must also also [register the UnityPerRequestHttpModule](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/msp-n-p/dn200217%28v%3Dpandp.30%29#remarks) in UnityMvcActivator.cs:

```
DynamicModuleUtility.RegisterModule(typeof(UnityPerRequestHttpModule));
```

With these configurations in place, Unity is able to resolve an appropriate SomeContext and supply this instance to the Service via constructor injection.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you should pass the context as a dependency, the context should be as short lived as possible, disposing it after every use. Here are some examples from my IDataService (which is injected using dep inj in my other services/facades)

```
    public DataService(IMapper mapper) : base(mapper) { }

    ...

    public UserDto GetUser(string ADUser)
    {
        Func<UserDto> action = () =>
        {
            return GetUsers(u => u.UserName == ADUser && u.Active == true).SingleOrDefault();
        };

        return ExecutorHandler(action, true);
    }

    public IList<UserDto> GetUsers(bool runSafeMode = true)
    {
        Func<IList<UserDto>> action = () =>
        {
            return GetUsers(_ => true);
        };

        return ExecutorHandler(action, runSafeMode);
    }

    private IList<UserDto> GetUsers(Expression<Func<User, bool>> predicate, bool runSafeMode = true)
    {
        Func<IList<UserDto>> action = () =>
        {
            using (var ymse = YMSEntities.Create())
            {
                var users = ymse.User
                    .Include(u => u.UserUserProfile)
                    .Include(m => m.UserUserProfile.Select(uup => uup.UserProfile))
                    .Include(m => m.UserUserProfile.Select(uup => uup.User))
                    .Include(m => m.UserUserProfile.Select(uup => uup.UserProfile.UserProfileModule))
                    .Where(predicate).OrderBy(u => u.UserName).ToList();

                return MappingEngine.Map<IList<UserDto>>(users);
            }
        };

        return ExecutorHandler(action, runSafeMode);
    }

    protected T ExecutorHandler<T>(Func<T> action, bool runSafeMode)
    {
        if (runSafeMode)
            return SafeExecutor(action);

        return Executor(action);
    }

    protected T SafeExecutor<T>(Func<T> action, int retryCount = 2)
    {
        try
        {
            return action();
        }
        catch (SqlException sqlEx)
        {
            if (retryCount == ConfigService.GetConfig("SQLRetryCount", 1))
            {
                // reached maximum number of retries
                throw;
            }

         ...
```

My IDataService has two implementations, one for online mode, one offline, setup like this in Unity (which a factory decides which one to use if wifi is enabled or not, could be something similar to inject proper DataService using different connection strings):

```
    unityContainer.RegisterType<IDataService, OfflineDataService>("OfflineDataService", new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager(), new InjectionConstructor(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData), ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<IMapper>()));

    unityContainer.RegisterType<IDataService, DataService>(new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager());
```

I would suggest placing a factory method here to determine at runtime the proper client (replace Entities.Create() with your injected entity creator factory):

```
    using (var ymse = YMSEntities.Create())
```

As for your comment about using transactions, in my opinion, the data layer shouldn't care about transactions, only the business layer which deals with many entities. Here is how I do it in my facade (multiple dataservice calls):

```
    public void SetTrailerWeightFull(Guid idShunter, Guid idTrailer, int? previousWeight, int weight, bool runSafeMode = true)
    {
        Action action = () =>
        {
            DataService.SetTrailerWeightFull(idTrailer, weight, runSafeMode);

            AddTrailerEvent(TrailerEventTypeEnum.SCALE_1, idTrailer, previousWeight, weight, "Weight Full", string.Empty, string.Empty);

            DataService.SetShunterWeightWeightFull(idShunter, idTrailer);
        };

        TransactionExecutor(action);
    }
```

Transaction code is all in one place shared by all:

```
    protected void TransactionExecutor(Action action, TransactionScopeAsyncFlowOption transactionScopeOption = TransactionScopeAsyncFlowOption.Suppress)
    {
        try
        {
            using (var scope = new TransactionScope(transactionScopeOption))
            {
                action();

                scope.Complete();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            LogErrorEvent(ex);

            throw;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for the feedback! I want to persist the instance of SomeContext for the duration of the HTTPRequest so that all occasions where my service interacts with the database can [operate within the same transaction](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn456843(v=vs.113).aspx#Anchor_1).  I have a WebAPI Action Filter BeginTransaction() in OnActionExecuting and Commit() in OnActionExecuted if there are no exceptions.  In my solution, I've instructed Unity to create/dispose of the context on a PerRequest basis so this should be a safe implementation.

Comment: @OneManBand the above works for transactions even if different contexts are used. I will update my answer to show you.

Comment: I misspoke earlier by saying 'where my service interacts with the database'.  In my architecture the service layer performs the business logic on data returned by the repositories which interact with the database.  So we agree that the data layer should have no awareness of transaction scope and my implementation is consistent with that philosophy.

Comment: Your code samples are intriguing and clearly work for you but because I was able to find a solution to exactly what I was searching for I have accepted my own answer.  However, I set a bounty to draw more attention to this question and because you replied with a thoughtful response I see no reason not to award it to you.  Even though I did not choose your answer I appreciate your assistance!

Comment: @OneManBand thanks for your diligence and thoughtfulness!

Answer (score -1):

I have used Unity Container to get dynamic DbContext in Repository/Service. Following code worked for me. Follow these steps

```
1. IMyDbContext.cs  

    public interface IMyDbContext: IDisposable  
    {  
     DbContextConfiguration Configuration { get; }  
     Database Database { get; }  
     DbSet<T> Set<T>() where T : class;  
     DbSet Set(Type type);  
     DbEntityEntry<T> Entry<T>(T entity) where T : class;  
     int SaveChanges();  
     Object MyContext { get; }  
    }  

2. MyDbContext.cs  

    public partial class MyDbContext : DbContext, IMyDbContext  
    {  
     Object IMyDbContext.MyDbContext  
     {  
      get  
      {  
       return new MyDbProject.MyDbContext();  
      }  
     }  
    }  

3. UnityConfig.cs file  

    // Database Types Registration  
    container.RegisterType<IMyDbContext, MyDatabaseProject.MyDbContext>();  
    // Repository/Services Types Registration  
    container.RegisterType<ICityManager, CityManager>();



4. MyRepository.cs

    public class MyRepository : IMyRepository  
    {  
    IMyDbContext dbContext;  
    MyDbContext myContext;  
    public MyRepository(IMyDbContext _dbContext)  
    {  
    dbContext = _dbContext;  
    myContext = (MyDbProject.MyDbContext)dbContext.MyDbContext;    
    }  
    public List<SP_GetEntity_Result> Get()  
    {  
    return myContext.SP_GetEntity().ToList();  
    }  
    }  

5. MyController.cs  

    private readonly IMyRepository _repo = null;  
    // Constructor of MyController  
    public MyyController(IMyRepository repo)  
    {  
    _repo = repo;  
    }
```

The _repo is instantiated by Dependency Injection using Unity Container.